# Export from Insomnia on Linux not working

Tags: linux-mint, insomnia

when I attempt to export data (I want to export all my requests and import them on a different PC) as per the manual (https://docs.insomnia.rest/insomnia/import-export-data), I keep failing to achieve that. I suppose it should store the export on my hard drive (Linux, so in my Home directory), but when I run the export, I only see an empty folder: [Empty Home folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK3sd.png).

When I try to store the exported data again, I already can see the previous stored export. However, when I attempt to locate the file on my hard drive using find command, it comes up empty. It appears as if Insomnia is storing the export on some kind of a virtual drive that I can't actually access. I couldn't find anything about this issue online, the few articles related to Insomnia export implicitly suggest that the export gets automatically stored on the real hard drive. Unfortunately, that is not my case. Also, when I open the import dialog on the target PC, it also opens an empty Home folder, so the problem is not restricted just to one PC.

Please, how do I get the export to work with my normal hard drive? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flathub/rest.insomnia.Insomnia/issues/4

"It seems like the flatpak exec command should include the additional argument --filesystem=home.

A temporary workaround is to edit the file at /var/lib/flatpak/[...]/rest.insomnia.Insomnia.desktop and add the argument to the Exec section."

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Insomnia
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --filesystem=home --command=/app/bin/insomnia --file-forwarding rest.insomnia.Insomnia --no-sandbox @@u %U @@
...
```

Note I added the --filesystem=home argument to the entry file."

Then restart the PC